# sapui5 How to add Footer for detail page

Tags: sapui5

I'm facing a small issue with Split App(Master-Detail). I'm not able to see Footer for the Detail Page.

After trying in all scenarios I found that because of `sap.m.Table`, I'm not able to get the Footer.

If I remove `sap.m.Table` I'm able to see Footer in Detail Page. I tried even with Semantic Buttons and Semantic footers but still no luck.

Can you please help me how can I fix this issue?

[image]

Below is my Code in XML ::

```
<mvc:View controllerName="sap.msbi_leaveAndAttendence.controller.LeaveBalanceReport" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified" xmlns:ui="sap.suite.ui.commons"
    xmlns:me="sap.me" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="Leave Balance Report" class="sapUiSizeCompact" showHeader="true" showFooter="true">
                <content>
                    <IconTabBar id="idIconTabBarNoIcons" expanded="{device>/isNoPhone}" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
                        <items>
                            <IconTabFilter text="All Leaves">
                                <Table id="idLeaveTable" class="sapUiSizeCompact" inset="true" items="{path: 'allLeavesModel>/allLeaves'}">
                                    <columns>
                                        <Column>
                                            <Text text="{i18n>startDate}"/>
                                        </Column>
                                        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                                            <Text text="{i18n>endDate}"/>
                                        </Column>
                                        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                                            <Text text="{i18n>noOfDays}"/>
                                        </Column>
                                        <Column>
                                            <Text text="{i18n>typeOfLeave}"/>
                                        </Column>
                                    </columns>
                                    <items>
                                        <ColumnListItem>
                                            <cells>
                                                <Text text="{allLeavesModel>from}"/>
                                                <Text text="{allLeavesModel>to}"/>
                                                <Text text="{allLeavesModel>used}"/>
                                                <Text text="{allLeavesModel>typeofleave}"/>
                                            </cells>
                                        </ColumnListItem>
                                    </items>
                                </Table>
                            </IconTabFilter>
                            <IconTabFilter text="Extraordinary Leaves"></IconTabFilter>
                        </items>
                    </IconTabBar>
                </content>
                <footer>
                    <OverflowToolbar>
                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        <Button type="Accept" text="Submit">
                            <layoutData><OverflowToolbarLayoutData moveToOverflow="false"/></layoutData>
                        </Button>
                    </OverflowToolbar>
                </footer>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: Does removing the `<App>` from your detail view help? It doesn't belong there anyway since it's a root element which is supposed to exist only once in the whole application

Comment: I found the issue in App.view.xml in my Split App Application, After applying CSS for that view, Im able to see footer

Comment: Great, but in UI5, applying custom CSS to fix a bug is always an anti-pattern which will lead to a maintenance hell soon or later. Please, provide minimal code with which we can reproduce the behavior so that we can find the real issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this issue by applying CSS for the main App.view.xml. After making overflow-y as hidden for the App.view.xml, Then i can see footer in my Detail page